# R: How to get rid of .lin in plinear nls

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

### Explanation

I am trying to fit an exponential curve to data in form `theta = x0 * exp(-kappa*l)`.

I do it firstly with `linear = lm( I(-log(temp.theta/x0)) ~ l + 0 )` where I get coefficient (`k = coef(linear)`) and then with `nls(temp.theta ~ I(x0 * exp(-k*l)) + 0, algorithm = "plinear" , start = list(k=k))` because I am not sure whether errors have the right nature with the `lm()`.

That decision came from reading a few Q&A's at stats.stackexchange about models where they discussed additive vs. multiplicative noise (=> error estimates?), which I haven't quite understand as I have just really basic knowledge of statistics. And since `lm()` and `nls()` give me different error estimates I intuitively think the latter could be more accurate.

The problem is the `nls(... , algorithm="plinear")` produces the coefficient which I want, but also the `.lin` thing which I understand to be multiplying the whole right side of the equation and hence messing up my model as it has sense only with intercept at `x0`.

### Questions

Is there a way to set `.lin = 1` or somehow turn it off?

Or alternatively: Is the `lm()` model sufficient for getting me reasonable error estimation?

### Reproducible example

(sorry for not including one right away, I thought it's better to ask in an abstract form):

```
l = c(0.001 , 0.002 , 0.003 , 0.004 , 0.005)
temp.theta = c(84.405 , 70.265 , 58.689 , 49.428 , 41.188)
x0 = 100
temp.lm = lm( I(-log(temp.theta/x0)) ~ l + 0 )
k=coef(temp.lm)
temp.nls = nls(temp.theta ~ I(x0 * exp(-k*l)) + 0, algorithm="plinear", start=list(k=k))
kappa=coef(temp.nls)
kappa
```

Comment: Use the default algorithm (i.e., Gauss-Newton algorithm) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the nls model it seems that the desired model has no linear components since `x0` is fixed so there is no reason to use plinear in the first place:

```
temp2.nls <- nls(temp.theta ~ x0 * exp(-k*l), start=list(k=k))
```

Regarding whether lm or nls is better have a look at the residuals.  Looking at the plots of the residuals, the residual of the first point seems to stick out suggesting it may not follow either model; however, with only 5 points we can't really say too much.

```
plot(resid(temp.lm), pch = 20, cex = 2, main = "lm Residuals")
plot(resid(temp2.nls), pch = 20, cex = 2, main = "nls Residuals")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is just a randomly chosen slice of data from a physical experiment where five curves were measured for different thiknesses of a material hence five points for every slice which by fitting all slices one by one (as shown here on one of them) produce another relationship. I am working on a much more complex question regarding this on stats.SE where most of it belongs, I think.

Comment: If data is available look at the residuals for both models and if the residuals form a ribbon around zero for one of the models but fan out or fan in for the other then the ribbon conforms better to the assumption of constant variance.

Comment: I've asked a question about this on [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89329/r-linearized-exponential-regression-by-lm-vs-non-linear-nls-regression). the residual analysis is hard since I have more than 300 of these fits and don't know which numbers to look for.

Comment: Try plotting the points and both model fits all on the same graph.